# Is there evidence to suggest that the change from the Gaul's Base 5 to Base 10 kicked off the European Enlightenment?

Tags: math-history

I was at a Mathematics teaching seminar talking about teaching primary school kids how to use *place value* (approximate rounding to base 10) to simplify addition and subtraction.

The leader of the seminar said:

> The Gauls were using [base 5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quinary) and it held back their development. When [Base 10 was imported](http://factmyth.com/factoids/fibonacci-introduced-the-modern-numeral-system-to-europe/) from India and the Arabic nations it really sped things up. This is when the [European Enlightenment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Enlightenment) really got kicked off.

I find this harder to believe for a couple of reasons. Arguably Enlightenment thinking comes from the [rationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalism) of [Descartes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ren%C3%A9_Descartes) in the early 1600's. (ie 400 years later).

Also it's hard to tie the cause of the European Enlightenment to a single cause. You might argue that the many [European Wars drove military engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Military_engineering#History) which drove science in chemistry and mechanical engineering. You might [argue that the incredible natural resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guns,_Germs,_and_Steel) of farmland, coal, iron and wood drove a 'perfect resources synergy' that lead to developments in science and engineering not available to other countries.

My question is: **Is there evidence to suggest that the change from the Gaul's Base 5 to Base 10 kicked off the European Enlightenment?**

Comment: Is there any evidence that Beethoven decided to become a poet when he first heard the Ramones perform at the Nuremberg trials?

Comment: **NO** [Gauls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaul) were subject to Roman control for five centuries, until the last Roman rump state, the Domain of Soissons, fell to the Franks in AD 486. [Roman number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_numerals) originated in ancient Rome and remained the usual way of writing numbers throughout Europe well into the Late Middle Ages. By the 11th century, Hindu–Arabic numerals had been introduced into Europe from al-Andalus, by way of Arab traders and arithmetic treatises. 1/2

Comment: Roman numerals, however, proved very persistent, remaining in common use in the West well into the 14th and 15th centuries, even in accounting and other business records (where the actual calculations would have been made using an abacus). Replacement by their more convenient "Arabic" equivalents was quite gradual. As you said [Europen Enlightenment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Enlightenment) was in 18th century. 2/2

Comment: *Conclusion* : historical evidence does not support the said thesis.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have references?